# Latexmk and fontspec

Tags: fontspec, latexmk

I'm trying to use `latexmk` with XeLaTeX. When I type:

```
latexmk.pl -xelatex -pvc -cd -auxdir=TeXAux myfile.tex
```

it all works fine. However I would like to use switches with XeLaTeX, such as `synctex=1`, and when I type:

```bash
latexmk.pl -pdflatex="xelatex --synctex=1 %O %S" -pvc -cd -auxdir=TeXAux myfile.tex
```

I have the following message from fontspec:

```
Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
The fontspecpackage requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
&c.
```

What did I not understand?

Comment: I get no error of this kind. What version of `latexmk` do you have?

Comment: Last MiKTeX's version: 4.37 (2 July 2013).

Answer (score 2):

OK. It works simply typesetting:

```
latexmk.pl -xelatex -synctex=1 -pvc -cd -auxdir=TeXAux myfile.tex
```

as I found with the help of

```
latexmk.pl -showextraoptions
```

However, I don't understand what was wrong with the previous command line…

Comment: I have the same version 4.37 (on Mac OS X), but, as I said, the other command line works too.

Comment: To diagnose what happened with the previous command line, you should look very carefully at the resulting output from `latexmk`.  It should say exactly what command line was used, and so you should see whether, for example, `xelatex` was actually invoked.  But the new command line (with the `-xelatex` and `-synctex=1` options) is usually a better way to go.